# Resize object tag to fit silverlight content

Tags: c#, javascript, html, silverlight

I am having the following problem:

I have a web page hosting silverlight content. The silverlight content is navigation aware, so it will always be the same html page and the same silverlight control. The content however will of course change when the user is navigating from one page inside the control to another.
Different pages have different size requirements and in some cases the final height of the content is unknown because the content is coming from a web service.

I want the height of the silverlight content to be dynamically according to what it actually needs. I saw many solutions to make the silverlight control fit the browser window, but I want the silverlight content to only have the actual height it needs and overflow when necessary, so that I can use the browsers scrollbars.

The page should also have a static background image, which is giving me some problems when the object tag is not exactly the size of the silverlight content.

The effect I want to achieve is more or less like in this web page:
http://www.codegarden.de/

The background should be in the html page when possible and the silverlight control should be the content in the middle part and should scroll with the browser scrollbar.

Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have your silverlight application execute javascript commands on the hosting page, that will in turn set the size of the `<Object>` tag.

Something like that:

```
using System.Windows.Browser; 

// set a global variable
HtmlPage.Window.Eval(String.Format("setSilverlightObjSize({0},{1});",newW,newH));
```

where `setSilverlightObjSize` is a javascript function you wrote in the hosting page.

soemthing like:

```
function SetObjectTagProps(w,h)
{
    var obj = document.getElementById("silverlightObj");
    obj.width = w;
    obj.height = h;
}
```

Comment: yes, I tried something similar, but how do I know how much space silverlight wants? I overwrote the ArrangeOverride method, but it seems that at this point silverlight already tries to fit into the area provided by the object container and the size I get as a parameter is too small...

Comment: The "How much silverlight wants" is really up to your application and to the way your layout is done. That should probably be a new question with some of your XAML code.

Comment: It's not very application specific. I only want silverlight takes all the space it needs. Most controls have a natural size or fit to their content. When I set the object tag to take 100% of the size I basically get the result that I want, except when the browser window gets to small or the content too big and silverlight tries to fit everything into a box that is too small instead of overflowing and causing scrollbars in the explorer window.

Comment: What do you want to happen in such a case then? you want the size to be 100% but never more than the browser's window? you want to let your silverlight to handle the layout inside in such a case?

Comment: no, I ALWAYS want my content to have full size. basically I don't care what the browsers windows size is. If the browser window is big enough to display my content fine, but if not, I don't care and I only expect the browser to display a scrollbar to scroll my content.

Comment: This might help you: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/alex_golesh/archive/2009/09/20/wpf-quick-tip-how-to-get-wpf-window-client-area-size.aspx

Comment: At the end I used a ScrollViewer filling the whole browser window, which is hosting my content. I would have preferred using the browser scrollbar, but I didn't find a solution that worked in time. I didn't try your last suggestions, but I'm going to mark this as the solution, because you provided good help for people with similar problems in the future.
Thanks again for the suggestions and research effort, appreciated!